# PHP mini-password-box: Too many loops

Tags: php

```
<div class="minipassbox" style="margin-top: 5px;">
               <?php
                   for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
                      $marginRight = ($i < 3 ? "margin-right:4px" : "");
                      echo "<div style='width:56px;float:left;{$marginRight}'>";
                      echo "<label for='param_kind{$i}' style='padding-left:4px;'>{$i}. Kind</label>";
                      echo "<select id='param_kind{$i}' class='selFields' name='param_kind{$i}' style='margin-top:3px'>";
                      echo  "<option selected='' value='-1'>--- </option>";
                      for($j = 1; $j <= 16; $j++) {
                         $selected = ($oRecherche->getParamValue("param_kind{$i}") == $j ? "selected='selected'" : "");
                         $option_text = ($j == 1 ? "&lt; 2 Jah." : $j + "Jahre");
                         echo "<option value='{$j}' {$selected}>{$option_text}</option>";
                      }
                      echo "</select>";
                      echo "</div>";
                   }   
               ?>
               <div style="clear:left"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Well, it's a loop. Any specific question? Beside, why don't you hard-code it if there isn't any dynamic in it?

Comment: Seperate your html from your login as much as possible!

Answer (score 4):

Two advices:

1. **Use [PHP alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)**

   When mixing HTML and PHP, it is a good practice to use  [PHP alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

   ```
   <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++): ?>
   ..
   <?php endfor ?>
   ```
2. **Improve the HTML code**

   - Use double quotes in tag attributes (HTML standard)
   - Try to respect indentation
   - Move style to css declarations

Final code proposition:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .minipassbox {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .minipassbox > div {
    width: 56px;
    float: left;
  }
  .minipassbox > div.lt3 {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  .minipassbox label {
    padding-left: 4px;
  }
  .selFields {
    margin-top: 3px;
  }
  .boxclear {
    clear: left;
  }
</style>
<div class="minipassbox">
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++): ?>
  <div <?php echo $i < 3 ? ' class="lt3"' : '' ?>
    <label for="param_kind<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?>. Kind</label>
    <select id="param_kind<?php echo $i ?>" class="selFields" name="param_kind<?php echo $i ?>">
      <option value="-1">--- </option>
      <?php for ($j = 1; $j <= 16; $j++): ?>
      <option value=""<?php echo $j ?>"<?php echo $oRecherche->getParamValue("param_kind$i") == $j ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $j == 1 ? "&lt; 2 Jah." : $j + "Jahre" ?></option>
      <?php endfor ?>
    </select>
  </div>
<?php endfor ?>
  <div class="boxclear"></div>
</div>
```